# How to use datePicker for increase date?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want increase date of `#Departure` with datePicker and wrote this code but get error.How to do this?

> detailed error: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

```
$('#Departure').datepicker('setDate',+1d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/0pfkx1js/) for only focusing date in datepicker

```
$('#nextday').click(function(e) {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate','c+1d');
});

$('#prevday').click(function(e) {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate','c-1d');
});
```

you have to prefix character 'c' to change relative to the selected date. if you want to set date into any place such as `input` tag, you could fire manually `onSelect` event of datepicker.

```
$('.ui-datepicker-current-day').click();
```

Refer to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/0pfkx1js/1/) for setting date information into any place such as `input` tag.

Comment: I use this code and error solved but don't set date to element : $('#Departure').datepicker('setDate','+1d')

Comment: Got it, Do you want to set date into any place such as `input` tag? refer to this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/0pfkx1js/1/